# OpenId Connect Provider Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, oauth-2.0, openid, openid-connect

I'm looking for a good package that can be used to implement a OpenId Connect Provider. I've found one called pyoidc but the documentation around it is not great at all. Can anyone suggest a different package or does any one have an example implementation of pyoidc?

Comment: Just a suggestion, you can remove the tag oauth2.0, this a openId question.

Answer (score 5):

OpenID Connect Provider implementation for Django framework:
https://github.com/juanifioren/django-openid-provider

It works for Python 3.4 and 2.7.

Do not hesitate to ask me if you have any further questions.

Greetings.

*-Ignacio*

Answer (score 2):

There are examples in the distribution. Just added another RP example (rp3) which I think should be easier to understand. Also started to add documentation.

Comment: could you provide a link?

Comment: The docs say shortly there will be a version for Py3.4... yet this answer seems to claim Py3 compatibility as of a year ago? What is the current, actual story?

Comment: The current situation is that it's only Python2. But I'm at PyCon US now and my personal sprint :-) will be to do the 2to3 porting during the sprint. Which is the next couple of days.

Answer (score 2):

In case someone needed. I've been working on [Authlib](https://authlib.org/) for a while, it has (will have) every OAuth 2 specifications included. OpenID Connect is included too. With Authlib v0.6+, one can create an OpenID Connect provider with ease in Flask. Useful links:

1. GitHub: https://github.com/lepture/authlib
2. OAuth 2 Documentation: https://docs.authlib.org/en/latest/flask/oauth2.html
3. OIDC Documentation: https://docs.authlib.org/en/latest/flask/oauth2.html

Yes, you need to read OAuth 2 documentation before reading OIDC documentation. Here is an [example for OAuth 2 provider](https://github.com/authlib/example-oauth2-server).

Answer (score 1):

A Japanese company, Gehirn, has open-sourced [their Python 3-compatible OpenID Connect library](https://github.com/GehirnInc/python-oidc) but the documentation is unfortunately pretty sparse.